# Dropdown menu not aligned under the title

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to add a drop-down menu to my site. I'm doing this by organizing the HTML as such:

```
<ul class="topnav">

  <li>
       SECTION TITLE
       <ul class="subnav">
         <li>One</li>
         <li>Two</li>
       </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

I have the CSS like this:

```
header ul.topnav li ul.subnav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; 
    top: 35px;
    background: blue;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 16%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I managed to get the jQuery working to slide down/up the submenu. My problem is with the styling: the dropdown menu appears at the left edge of the screen, instead of sliding down from under SECTION TITLE. You can perhaps get a better view of my problem from my website: [link here](http://mayar.abertay.ac.uk/~1204925/temp/index.php) (the menu is at the top, hovering over elements will display the sub menu)

Since `position: absolute` I would expect the `ul.subnav` to appear relative to the parent element, in this case the parent `li` containing SECTION TITLE. However it looks like the position of the `ul.subnav` is relative to the top left corner.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with the way the css is setup I can't even begin to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to float all the topnavs li left but you are floating li's children to left unnecessarily like sections with ids like whithacking etc. All those float lefts are pulling the topnav li's to the farmost left you can check it in chrome by hovering over the html. You need to remove all those floats and width. Anchors will take width automatically once you remove floats.
Use this

```
ul.topnav > li{
position:relative;
float:left;
width:15%
}
```

and then style your left

Comment: what is a `float: li`?

Comment: My bad, I meant to write float:left

Answer (score 1):

the element is positioned `absolute`, relative to the first parent element which is position: absolute, relative or fixed. Add this:

```
header ul.topnav > li {
    position: relative;
}
```

and it will work.